# How do I remove BOM characters when exporting to csv?

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I'm exporting some data from wordpress to a csv file. All works fine except I'm getting these characters ï»¿ in the beginning of the first cell of the exported csv. From what I've read they are Byte Order Marks (BOM) but I can't find a solution to get rid of them.

Here is my code:

```
GLOBAL $wpdb;
    global $current_user;

$query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_type' => 'surf-school', 'author'=>$current_user->ID));
    foreach($query->posts as $post) {

    $surfschool_id = get_the_ID();

    $enquiries_results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT first_name, last_name, email FROM wp_web_leads WHERE surf_school_id = $surfschool_id");
        foreach ($enquiries_results as $data) {

        echo "$data->first_name, $data->last_name, $data->email\n";
    }
 }

$FileName = "Export_Enquiries.csv";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $FileName . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public'); 
exit();
```